# iPhone app that displays temperature as a notification badge

Tags: iphone, applications, software-recommendation

I'm looking for an app similar to [Fahrenheit](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fahrenheit-weather-temperature/id426939660?mt), that gives a notification badge indication of the current temperature.  A problem with Fahrenheit that I have is that it's too slow in updating.  I need something that updates the badge at least every 30 minutes (so I don't have to open up the app to get it to refresh).

Answer (score 3):

There are several Weather Apps that perform this function. The one I am currently using (as I live in Canada and it has good Canadian weather support) is [Degrees](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/degrees-accurate-canadian/id430737738?mt=8).

You could also try [Weather Live](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/weather-live/id464770748?mt=8) or [eWeather HD](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/eweather-hd-weather-forecast/id401533966?mt=8). I'm sure there are many more.

One limitation of those badges, if you live in a part of the world like mine, is lack of negative numbers in the badge. Since I use Celsius, this is an issue even this time of year. :)

Answer (score 1):

The app [Weather Live](https://itunes.apple.com/NO/app/id464770748?mt=8&affId=2157527) has the ability to show the current forecasted temperature on the application badge.

I haven't tested it myself, but it seems promising. Not free, though.

Answer (score 1):

There are two apps that I know of that put the temperature as a notification badge.  Both are free with inapp subscriptions to get rid of advertising

- [Weatherzone](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/weatherzone-weather-forecasts/id409060691).
- [Carrot Weather](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/carrot-weather-alerts-radar/id961390574)

With both of these, you get the badge temperature and the regular notifications and widgets.

Comment: @Thinkr why?  It shows up very clearly on the App Store. There is no point in repeating info that wasn’t asked for to begin with

Answer (score -1):

### [Weather](https://apps.apple.com/app/weather/id1069513131)

> Get the weather forecast in a beautiful and powerful app. See current and forecasted weather with a smart layout that updates as conditions change. And view precipitation, air quality, and temperature maps to see different conditions near you.

- Available on iPhone, iPad, Mac and Apple Watch.

There's a Weather widget that allows you to get the weather forecast (as well as current weather directly to your Home Screen or Lock Screen. This is the middle-sized widget but there's also a large-sized and small-sized ones:

[image: Screenshot taken on iPhone of the Weather widget showing the weather at Etiwanda Falls Trail]

There are also Lock Screen Weather widgets.

Also:

> You can receive notifications from the Weather app when precipitation and certain severe weather events are forecasted in your current location.

<sub>*(From [Manage weather notifications on iPhone](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/manage-weather-notifications-iph39ae9474a/ios))*</sub>